# CGIHTTPServer and Python script

Tags: python, macos, cgi

I am currently writing a python program which prints HTML page using `sys.stdout.print()` the script name is hellocgi.py and it is inside a cgi-bin directory on the Desktop on my Mac OS X.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Content-type: text/html \r\n\r\n")
sys.stdout.write("<!doctype html><html><head><title>Hello World</title></head>")
sys.stdout.write("<body><h2>Hello CGI</h2></body></html>")
```

Then I am running the command `python -m CGIHTTPServer` inside the cgi-bin directory, and when I am going to the url `localhost:8000/hellocgi.py` what I get is the source code inside firefox.

If I try to run `python -m CGIHTTPServer` outside the cgi-bin, I get an error on url `localhost:8000/cgi-bin/`:

> Error response
>
> Error code 403.
>
> Message: CGI script is not a plain file ('/cgi-bin/').
>
> Error code explanation: 403 = Request forbidden -- authorization will
>   not help.

On URL `localhost:8000/cgi-bin/hellocgi.py` firefox prompt me to download the source code.

Python version: 2.7.5
Mac OS X: 10.9

python -m CGIHTTPServer log:

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2014 18:34:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2014 18:34:51] code 403, message CGI script is not a plain file ('/cgi-bin/')
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2014 18:34:51] "GET /cgi-bin/ HTTP/1.1" 403 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2014 18:36:01] "GET /cgi-bin/hellocgi.py HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/CGIHTTPServer.py", line 253, in run_cgi
    os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Jun/2014 18:36:01] CGI script exit status 0x7f00
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/CGIHTTPServer.py", line 378, in <module>
    test()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/CGIHTTPServer.py", line 374, in test
    SimpleHTTPServer.test(HandlerClass, ServerClass)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 216, in test
    BaseHTTPServer.test(HandlerClass, ServerClass)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 599, in test
    httpd.serve_forever()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 236, in serve_forever
    poll_interval)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 155, in _eintr_retry
    return func(*args)
```

Any help?

Comment: if you try `localhost:8000/cgi-bin/` then server is looking for `cgi-bin/index.html` to serve it, if there is no `index.html` (and you have no rights to list folders) then server send `ERROR 403`. Did you add `#!/usr/bin/python` in `hellocgi.py` ? Linux/Unix (and MacOS) needs this line to run script using Python. If you add `#!/usr/bin/perl` it will try to run this script with Perl. Linux/Unix recognize script by this line, not by file extension. Did you try to run `hellocgi.py` in command line (console/termina) without `python` (not `python hellocgi.py` but `hellocgi.py` or `./hellocgi.py`) ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your comment help me to understand a simple fact, that the file didn't have execution permissions so I gave it with the command `sudo chmod +x hellocgi.py` and then I run the server again and works. Thank you very match!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Content-type: text/html \r\n\r\n")
sys.stdout.write("<!doctype html><html><head><title>Hello CGI</title></head>")
sys.stdout.write("<body><h2>Hello CGI</h2></body></html>")
```

and add premision to the file chmod +x querys.py